# Update to m2e 1.6 resulted in "Conflicting lifecycle mapping" error

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e, maven-war-plugin, m2e-wtp

After I've run an update in my Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2) I got m2e 1.6.1.20150625-2338 installed. For a project where I use `maven-war-plugin` now I get the following errors in the problems view:

[image: problems view]

Full text:

> Conflicting lifecycle mapping (plugin execution
>   "org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (execution:
>   war-standalone, phase: package)"). To enable full functionality,
>   remove the conflicting mapping and run Maven->Update Project
>   Configuration.
>
> Conflicting lifecycle mapping (plugin execution
>   "org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (execution:
>   war-standalone, phase: package)"). To enable full functionality,
>   remove the conflicting mapping and run Maven->Update Project
>   Configuration.

The plugin configuration didn't cause a problem with the previous version of m2e. It looks ok in the pom, nothing unusual:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>war-standalone</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>war-overlay</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The lifecycle-mapping for `maven-war-plugin` isn't configured in the pom. I checked if it is in parent poms but couldn't find anything. None is in the workspace lifecycle mappings metadata as well.

Then I noticed m2e-wtp plugin (where the mapping seems to come from) was still an old version. I updated it to 1.2.0.20150602-1740 but it didn't resolve the problem.

Any idea how to track down where is the conflicting mapping or maybe how to resolve the issue properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has been reported and a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471840) has been created for that.

Note that it has been fixed in m2e v1.6.2.

Comment: I missed that update till now, thanks for the disclosure.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same conflict problem when upgrading from m2e 1.6.0 to m2e 1.6.1, but on the `maven-compiler-plugin` configured for using the groovy-eclipse-compiler.

After investigation, I found [this commit](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471038) that might very well be at the origin of the error since it changes the way configurators are loaded and can result in loading more configurators. In my case, it seems like both default compiler configurator *and* groovy eclipse compiler configurator are loaded thus resulting in a conflict.

Comment: Ok, but have you been able to fix the problem somehow?